# How to include bootstrapper application to WIX msi installer for checking .NET framework?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, wix, installation

I have created WIX installer with custom UI. I want check if there is no .NET framework 4.5 then Installer should ask and install .NET framework.
I know that for this I have to create separate bootstrapperproject, but I do not want to do that. because I want to keep my Installation UI and use only one msi.
How can I do that without creating separate project, or how can I refer to that project from my msi?

Comment: why cant you  create another installer MSI, and then run a custom action to install .net framework and wait until it is successful ?

Comment: Where can I find example of that?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that we cannot have two MSIEXEC in parallel.  Hence you would not be able to do that.  Did you try embeddedChainer element http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/embeddedchainer.html ?

Comment: No I didn't I try to set this in my xml, but I dont know if it help or not. I have created another project. <BootstrapperApplicationRef
         Id="ManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost">
      <Payload
        SourceFile="$(var.SetupBoostrapper.TargetPath)"/>
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>

Comment: [I commented on something similar yesterday, maybe have a look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54869308/wix-getting-wixui-minimal-to-show-when-bootstrapper-is-used#comment96513036_54869308).